# Querying distinct count values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

Consider the following table:

```
ID   |      IP
--------------------
162  |  34.56.12.90
162  |  34.56.12.90
25   |  12.23.56.78
25   |  12.23.56.78
162  |  12.23.56.78
92   |  34.56.12.90
92   |  12.23.56.78
```

I'm trying to query distinct values of each ID and their respective number of times appearing based on different IP. 2 similar ID & IP is considered as only 1 record.

I've tried

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(1) AS 'NUM' 
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```

How can I put the IP into account?

The result I want is:

```
ID  |  NUM
----------------
162 |   2
25  |   1
92  |   2
```

Comment: `COUNT ( DISTINCT IP )`

Comment: @Squirrel: your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to use COUNT (DISTINCT [column name] )

```
SELECT ID, COUNT( DISTINCT IP ) AS 'NUM' 
FROM table
GROUP BY ID
```